# Removal of overlapping of datetime in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which stores login and logout time. Help me with removal of overlapping of datetime between the rows

i have the Table like this

```
id | login_time           | logout_time
1  |'2017-02-20 11:20:00' | '2017-02-20 12:10:00'
2  |'2017-02-20 12:13:00' | '2017-02-20 12:40:00'
3  |'2017-02-20 12:30:00' | '2017-02-20 13:10:00'
4  |'2017-02-20 13:20:00' | '2017-02-20 13:30:00'
5  |'2017-02-20 13:25:00' | '2017-02-20 14:20:00'
```

The Output Should be like

```
login_time           | logout_time
2017-02-20 11:20:00  | 2017-02-20 12:10:00
2017-02-20 12:13:00  | 2017-02-20 13:10:00
2017-02-20 13:20:00  | 2017-02-20 14:20:00
```

Help me.

Comment: I don't see the overlaps.

Comment: Is overlap at agent level?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Please check logout record 2 and loging record 3.the datetime is overlapping.

Comment: @skelwa: Yes, if its overlapping. want to remove that and show as single record.

Comment: But then 2 and 3 are for different agents, so how is that an overlap?

Comment: @skelwa: I want to check on day level.

Comment: I dont understand why you want to remove data? Its not a dupe or overlap? so why do you want to remove them?

Comment: @connorg98: I am not removing data. i want to do report on day level. so that i will come to know the gap where no agents are not available.

Comment: Ok that wouldve been better if you put that inside the question no problem :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to your output sample I changed my query and checked it returns your expected result set

```
select t1.logintime,t2.logoutime from
(
select F1.logintime,F1.rank from 
(
select 
  t.logintime,
  CASE WHEN @prevRank = logintime THEN @currRank
       WHEN @prevRank := logintime THEN @currRank := @currRank + 1
   END AS rank
from (
  select  min(login_time) as logintime from time_table
group by hour(login_time) 
  ) t
  cross join (SELECT @currRank := 0, @prevRank := NULL) r

  ) as F1
 ) t1 

inner join

(
select F2.logoutime,F2.rank from
(
select 
  t.logoutime,
  CASE WHEN @preRank = logoutime THEN @curRank
       WHEN @preRank := logoutime THEN @curRank := @curRank + 1
   END AS rank
from (
  select  min(logout_time) as logoutime from time_table
group by hour(logout_time) 
  ) t
  cross join (SELECT @curRank := 0, @preRank := NULL) r

  ) F2
  ) as  t2

  on t1.rank = t2.rank
```

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin: No its doesn't work. You are taking single record of every agent. I want to remove the overlapping based on the records.Please check the output. you might be confused for keeping agent_name. i made changes in question.

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin: Its working but the result is not as expected. Logout is taking from previous record, actually i should take for next record where the logintime between next record of login and logout. Please help me.

Comment: can you give me sample data for that where not working?

Answer (score 0):

correlated subquery with "exists" should solve your problem

```
select login_time,logout_time 
from time_table TT1
where not exists 
(
select 1
from time_table TT2
where TT1.login_time  >= TT2.login_time AND 
TT1.login_time <=TT2.logout_time and tt1.id > tt2.id )
```

SQl fiddle [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/140047/33/0)

Comment: @learningstudent i have remodified my ans pls look if it workS for you

Comment: its not working as expected. Its ignoring complete record.