# deleting overlapped data in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having trouble deleting records in my database.
table name is price_price and has price_no as pk, and main_item_no, sub_item_no, price_date, price.
my problem is that some records are overlapped. such as,

```
price_no  main_item_no  sub_item_no  price_date  price  
**1 /        1  /           1  /          2020-09-25 / 200  
2     /    1  /           1  /          2020-09-25 / 200  
3    /     1  /           1   /         2020-09-25 / 200**  
4    /     1  /           2   /         2020-09-25 / 300  
5    /     2  /           1   /         2020-09-25 / 400  
etc
```

how can I delete rows that are overlapping in mysql??
please help

Comment: Hi, interesting, perhaps this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51189766/removal-of-overlapping-of-datetime-in-mysql

Comment: Please define overlapping.  What rows do you ant deleted?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete *duplicates*, then you can use `join`:

```
delete t
    from t left join
         (select min(price_no) as min_price_no, 
                 main_item_no, sub_item_no, price_date, price 
          from t
          group by main_item_no, sub_item_no, price_date, price 
         ) tt
         on t.price_no = tt.price_no
    where tt.price_no is null;
```